# What distribution does the random variable X follow if we have to model the waiting time untill the n^th success?

Tags: variables, random, distribution

What distribution does the random variable X follow if we have to model the waiting time untill the n^th success?

Comment: This question would probably get better traction [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com), given that it contains no programming.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) - The geometric distribution gives the probability that the first occurrence of success requires k independent trials, each with success probability p. If the probability of success on each trial is p, then the probability that the kth trial (out of k trials) is the first success is

```
Pr(X=k)=(1-p)^(k-1) * p
```

UPDATE

I might misunderstand the question, you have to clarify it - n^th success means single success at the n^th position, or count of successes being exactly n. FOr the first case, answer is geometric distribution, bu for the second case the answer would be [Negative Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Comment: That would give number of trials, not time until...  From there it's straightforward to calculate expected time, but not the distribution without more info.  Either way, the question doesn't belong on SO so I'd ask that you not encourage the OP.